# How to multiply very large sparse matrix in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, sparse-matrix

I have a very large sparse tensor `input_a` with shape: [20k, 20k], and a dense tensor `input_b` with shape: [20k, 512]. nnz(input_a) is about 400k (There are 400k nonzero values in input_a). I would like to multiply these two tensor, to get the output tensor `output` with shape: [20k, 512]. If I use `tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul` to multiply input_a and input_b, there will be an error: (with tensorflow version v1.8)

> Cannot use GPU when output.shape[1] * nnz(a) > 2^31"

If output.shape[1] is 20k, it might make sense, because 20k * 400k = 8000000000 > 2^31 = 2147483648. But, I think output.shape[1] should be 512 in this case?

My code:

`input_a`: shape [20k, 20k]

`input_b`: shape [20k, 512]

`output`: shape [20k, 512]

```
output = tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(input_a, input_b)
```

Then I will get the error message.

If I transform input_a to a dense tensor and then use `tf.matmul`, it works, but it might cost a lot of memory and time?

```
dense_input_a = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(dense_input_a)
output = tf.matmul(dense_input_a, input_b, a_is_sparse = True)
```

Why the error occurred and how should I multiply these two tensor in a efficient way? Thanks!